# The package system is broken also python 3.10 error

Tags: package-management, updates, dependencies

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

python3.10: Depends: python3.10-minimal (= 3.10.8-1+focal1) but 3.10.8-1+focal1 is installed
            Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.8-1+focal1) but 3.10.3-1+focal1 is installed
python3.10-minimal: Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.8-1+focal1) but 3.10.3-1+focal1 is installed
                    Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3 is installed
```

Comment: Just posting error output is not a proper question. Context is needed. What version are you using, what are you trying to do.

Comment: Ubuntu Focal (20.04) comes with Python 3.8 (not 3.10). Your output suggests that you have changed the version of Python3 on your system from 3.8 to 3.10 using some non-Ubuntu source. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes i have changed python3.8 to 3.10 how can i remove it as i have tried many times but nothing helps also i am trying to update my Ubuntu but it always give error trying to do many thing but error shows up.